# JavaScript - find the same first element using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've got to create var with few elements:

```
var arrNum = [4,7,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]
```

1. I need to find first number that is the same in array using for loop. So it will be "4" and "4"
2. I need to create var sameIndex and adjust the same number to sameIndex and print after for loop

So I did loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++){

  console.log("")
  console.log("Loop number is " + i)

  if(arrNum[i] === arrNum[i]{
    break
    sameIndex = going[i]
  }

}
console.log(sameIndex)
```

It's not working.

Comment: what do you want to find? btw, `arrNum[i] === arrNum[i]` is a self check and if not `NaN` always `true`.

Comment: I want to find the first the same number in array, so it is "4" and "4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It returns the first index of the given element in the array:

```js
var arrNum = [4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10];
var i;
var sameIndex = -1;
for (i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
  if (arrNum.indexOf(arrNum[i]) !== i) {
    console.log('This is the second occurrence of', arrNum[i]);
    sameIndex = arrNum.indexOf(arrNum[i]);
    break;
  }
}

console.log('The indices are', sameIndex, 'and', i);
```

Comment: Oh thanks it helps ! Is this only way to use IndexOf ?  Is there any other ways to do this ?

One more time thank you very much !

Comment: Using `indexOf` was just the first thing that came to my mind. Certainly, there are other ways to do it. [This page](http://js-algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/2016/01/25/find-duplicates-in-an-array/) for example seems to do it a little differently.

Comment: this is a very slow approach, because it iterates if no dupe is in the array n*n times.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrNum = [4,7,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];

for(var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++){
  for(var j = i+1; j < arrNum.length; j++) {
    if(arrNum[i] === arrNum[j]) {
      console.log('value: '+arrNum[i]+' index1: '+i+' index2: '+j);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the first duplicate, then use :

```
var arrNum = [4,7,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];

function firstDuplicate(array){
  var history = [];
  for(var element of array){
    if(history.indexOf(element)<0)
      //not in the history yet
      history.push(element);
    else
      return element;
  }

  return null; //or any distinctive value
}

var fDup = firstDuplicate(arrNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table and display the value.

```js
var array = [4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (hash[array[i]]) {
        console.log('first dupe: ' + array[i]);
        break;
    }
    hash[array[i]] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working script:

```
var arrNum = [4,7,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];
var sameIndex = -1, going = new Array();
for(var j = 0; j < arrNum.length; j++) {
  for(var i = 1; i < arrNum.length; i++){
    console.log("Loop number is " + j + ", " + i)
    if(arrNum[i] === arrNum[j]){
      sameIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(sameIndex > 0) {
    console.log(j, sameIndex)
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the original array and if the value is not in a comparison array - push it into a common numbers array. The first item in that common numbers array is the target.

```js
var origArray = [4,7,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,10];
var newArray = [];
var commonNums = [];


origArray.forEach(function(item,i) {
  newArray.indexOf(item) == -1
    ? newArray.push(item)
    : commonNums.push({item: item, index:i});   
})

if(commonNums.length > 0) {
 var firstCommonNum = commonNums[0].item;
 var firstCommonNumIndex = commonNums[0].index;
 
 console.log("common number " + firstCommonNum);
 console.log("Loop number is " + firstCommonNumIndex);
}
```